# How to save a ManyToMany relationship from a ModelForm in Django

Tags: django

I'm not sure to save my ManyToMany relationship. I found my exact problem in this thread: [Django embedded ManyToMany form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036142/django-embedded-manytomany-form), except instead of Sales and Products models, I have models that make up a movie.

I tried the solution, but I receive a syntax error. I don't understand how Django should link the EquipmentModel, LightModel, and ActorModel to the ManyToMany relationship in MovieModel. So far (before trying the other thread's solution), the CharFields that are displayed on the form for LightModel, EquipmentModel, and ActorModel are not linked to the ManyToManyField in MovieModel. So when I save the forms and try to access a particular Movie's actors, all I see is a blank list. The solution from the other thread seems to make sense since it tries to link the models to the ManyToMany relationship in MovieModel, but I don't understand how Django knows which MovieModel to add to (how does it get the correct movieID?).

On a side note, is there a way to check for duplicate movies when the user presses the 'Submit' button on the form? I want to avoid creating duplicates.

views.py:

```
def add_movie(request, movieID=""):

    if request.method == "POST":
            form = MovieModelForm(request.POST)
            eform = EquipmentModelForm(request.POST)
            lform = LightModelForm(request.POST)
            aform = ActorModelForm(request.POST)

            print 'checking form'
            print request.POST.items()
            if form.is_valid() and eform.is_valid() and lform.is_valid() and aform.is_valid():
                    print 'form is valid'
                    movie_to_add = form.save()
                    e = eform.save()
                    l = lform.save()
                    a = aform.save()
                    movie_to_add.actors.add(a)
                    movie_to_add.lights.add(l)
                    movie_to_add.equipments.add(e)

            #       return HttpResponseRedirect('/data')
    else:
           # code for create forms ....


    return render_to_response('add_movie.html', {'form':form, 'eform':eform,'lform':lform, 'aform':aform,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Other code that may help:

forms.py

```
class LightModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = LightModel

class ActorModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = ActorModel

class EquipmentModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = EquipmentModel

class MovieModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
            model = MovieModel
            fields = ("title", "rank")
```

models.py

```
class EquipmentModel(models.Model):
    equip = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class ActorModel(models.Model):
    actor = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class LightModel(models.Model):
    light = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class MovieModel(models.Model):
    rank = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5000, decimal_places=3)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    equipments = models.ManyToManyField(EquipmentModel, blank=True, null=True)
    actors = models.ManyToManyField(ActorModel, blank=True, null=True)
    lights = models.ManyToManyField(LightModel, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

Edit: removed unnecessary **init** and fields thanks to DTing

Edit2: Fixed!

Comment: Can you add the traceback of the SyntaxError that you are getting to the question description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a whole lot of stuff going wrong here in addition to what spulec said.

Your models.py look okay.

```
class EquipmentModel(models.Model):
    equip = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class ActorModel(models.Model):
    actor = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class LightModel(models.Model):
    light = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class MovieModel(models.Model):
    rank = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5000, decimal_places=3)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    equipments = models.ManyToManyField(EquipmentModel, blank=True, null=True)
    actors = models.ManyToManyField(ActorModel, blank=True, null=True)
    lights = models.ManyToManyField(LightModel, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

You don't need to override the `__init__` method on forms if you are not changing anything on init. You also don't need to be explicit about the fields if you want to include them all.

```
class LightModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = LightModel

class ActorModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = ActorModel

class EquipmentModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = EquipmentModel

class MovieModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = MovieModel
            fields = ("title", "rank")
```

your view doesn't really make sense unless for every movie you are trying to add you also want to:

1. add a new movie to the db using the submitted post data
2. create one actor object and add to db
3. create one light object and add to db
4. create one equipment object and add to db
5. take those three objects and add them to another movie's m2m relationships.

   - This other movie is some movie that you pulled from the urlconf and passed to your view, not the one you just created.

This all seems a little strange.

what i think you want to do is create all the equipment, actors and lights objects so they are in your db already, and use the default m2m formfield widget to select them when adding a movie.

so:

forms.py

```
class MovieModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MovieModel
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^add_movie/$', add_movie)
```

views.py:

```
def add_movie(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = MovieModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('success')
    else:
        form = MovieModelForm()

    context = {'form':form }

    return render_to_response('some_template.html', context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

you could combine adding actors, lights, and equipment into the same form but that's a bit much for me to write out right now.

As far as modifying your original code to add those lights, actors, and equipment to the movie you just created, you could do this:

```
        if form.is_valid() and eform.is_valid() and lform.is_valid() and aform.is_valid():
                new_movie = form.save()
                e = eform.save()
                l = lform.save()
                a = aform.save()
                new_movie.actors.add(a)
                new_movie.lights.add(l)
                new_movie.equipments.add(e)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, I wanted the user to add a movie to my database by entering some elements that are present in that movie, such as actors, lighting techniques, equipment used, etc. 

So the idea was to use a form that asks for the title of the movie the user wishes to enter into my database, the actors involved, the lights used, the movie ranking, and the equipment present in the movie. Once the user clicks 'Submit', that movie and its elements would be saved. The user can then go to the url '.../movies/' to see the list of all movies in the database or '.../<movie title here>/'

Comment: (continued) to see the particular movie profile by its title. The movie profile would then list the movie's title, actors, lights, etc.. everything that was entered through the form.

Comment: I don't have the user select from a list of actors since there's nothing in the database yet. Which is why I created a bunch of ModelForms that asks for the lights, actors, and equipments which should then be associated with the movie that the user just created in my database through the form. The part I don't get is how to link the actors and everything to the MovieModel's ManyToMany relationship. I created the actors, lights, equip independently of the MovieModel, so MovieModel doesn't know anything about them. The movieID doesn't work, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
movie_to_add = get_object_or_404(MovieModel, id=movieID)
```

Comment: I don't understand how Django knows which movieID should be linked to the ActorModel, LightModel, and EquipmentModel. Also, movieID shouldn't be defaulted to an empty string, but I'm not sure how the ID's are passed?